# Android twitter login button [firebase auth] error : Twitter: Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, twitter-fabric

This is displayed when I run my application, the twitter button can't be clicked and is not working:

[image: img]

This is the code for the twitter login button:

```
mLoginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_twitter_login);
    mLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "twitterLogin:success" + result);
            handleTwitterSession(result.data);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.w(TAG, "twitterLogin:failure", exception);
            updateUI(null);
        }
    });
```

I put this code in method `OnCreate`:

```
 TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig(
                getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key),
                getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

I set in OnActivityResult like this:

```
mLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

This is the code for the method `twitterSession` which I call in the `onClick` twitter button:

```
 private void handleTwitterSession(TwitterSession session) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleTwitterSession:" + session);
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    showProgressDialog();
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
            session.getAuthToken().token,
            session.getAuthToken().secret);

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
```

Ant then i get error like this:

```
 E/Twitter: Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Application.java`'s `onCreate()`, add this code:

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig(
                getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key),
                getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));

final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
                .kits(new TwitterCore(authConfig))
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .debuggable(true)
                .build();

Fabric.with(fabric);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for help @Cristik . I try this code but still error like that "Twitter: Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()" . maybe anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

in OnCreate, put setContentView function AFTER the following code, NOT BEFORE :

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig(
            getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key),
            getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```